# Disable / Hide the Follow link in Callout action

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to hide the Follow link from Callout actions using JavScript/Jquery, how can this be done?

Comment: Does my answer help you? If so, please mark it as answer. If not, please give us some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow there steps:

Starting point (disable follow in callout / hoverpanel):

[image]

1. Go to site settings

[image]

2. Click on Manage Site Featuers

[image]

3. Deactivate Following Content

[image]

4. Now the Button "Follow" in callouts is gone

[image]

Hope this helped!